# Configure nginx to serve Angular 15 NX monorepo with module federation

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-module-federation

I have an Angular 15 app within an NX Monorepo with a few renotes.
The issue I am facing is configuring nginx to serve the shell and the remotes.
When I click on a route to navigate, the shell does not actually render the remote, but the default  nginx index.html (which I do have in the root).

The `root` nginx folder looks like this:

```
/shell/* <-- each folder contains all the build files (css, js, remoteEntry.mjs, index.html, etc)
/remote1/*
/remote2/*
/remote3/*
index.html
```

And this is the `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 9090;
    listen [::]:9090;
    server_name 192.168.1.175;

    include mime.types;

    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;

    types {
        application/javascript mjs;
    }

    location ~ ^/shell(?:/(.*))?$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri /index.html =404;    }
        
    location ~ ^/remote1(?:/(.*))?$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri /index.html =404;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/remote2(?:/(.*))?$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri /index.html =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/remote3(?:/(.*))?$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri /index.html =404;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

In the `shell` I've got a menu and when I click on it, for example to got to `remote1`, I do get navigated to `/shell/remote1`. However, the rendered page is the default `index.html` from nginx instead of `shell` having `remote1` embedded in it.

My `webpack.prod.config.js` looks like this:

```
const { withModuleFederation } = require('@nrwl/angular/module-federation');
const config = require('./module-federation.config');
module.exports = withModuleFederation({
  ...config,
  remotes: [
    ['remote1', 'http://192.168.1.175:9090/remote1'],
    ['remote2', 'http://192.168.1.175:9090/remote2'],
    ['remote3', 'http://192.168.1.175:9090/remote3']
  ],
});
```

I have also set `"baseHref": "/xxxx/"` in each module's `project.json`.

Any suggestion on how to do this properly? Been fighting with it for hours.

Of course, works just fine with ng serve.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar structure in my code. But in this original code snippet, it says:

For Ex.

```
location ~ ^/remote1(?:/(.*))?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri /index.html =404;
}
```

but a solution that came up is adding the name of the remote before the index because you want to look for the specific index.html in its subdirectory.

Solution Ex.

```
location ~ ^/remote1(?:/(.*))?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri remote1/index.html =404;
}
```

From what was understood of the question this is the solution that was tested for the specific problem. There may be other issues that I did not answer in my solution.

This solution might not be the most efficient or effective. Can build off this answer for anyone who wants to answer.